# Unable to connect with SignalR and Ocelot gateway with any available transports. Error 404 "No Connection with that ID"

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-3.1, gateway, asp.net-core-signalr, ocelot

I have a react website in which I am trying to connect to SignalR hub on my .net core server via ocelot gateway.

I am unable to connect to hub and get a 404 error "No Connection with that ID". I have only one server instance running and no load balancer is involved.
[SignalR Hub Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO47b.png)
[SignalR Hub Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJGi6.png)

Even though the negotiate call is always successful.

```
{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"BWKJZHDMQkfYV9Qz5RNtHg","connectionToken":"nZjyl8Gpm7jF1MtWipHdPw","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
```

WebSocket and Server Sent Events are not working at all and on Long Polling, 404 is returned "No Connection with that ID".

Network call logs are: [Network calls logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miQTL.png)

I have added all possible routes for ocelot. I am out of ideas on what to do now.

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub/{everything}",
  "ReRouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
  "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 5009
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub/{everything}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
},
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub?{everything}",
  "ReRouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
  "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 5009
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub?{everything}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
},
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub",
  "ReRouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
  "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 5009
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/bookingCancelNotificationHub",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
},
```

I have observed that the connectionId returned in response to the negotiate call is not used to connect to hub and instead the connectionToken value is used as the value for "id" query string parameter.

```
https://xxxx.se/bookingCancelNotificationHub?id=OHhTeLj9uKVHGh-nBeIBwA&access_token=7b082653-7283-41ef-8337-a22b6dc239f1%7CPASS
```

I have following configuration in my Ocelot Gateway project

```
ConfigureServices(services =>
                     {
                         services.AddCors(options =>
                         {
                             var isCustomOriginsAllowed = _configuration.GetValue<bool>("IsCustomOriginsAllowed");
                             if (isCustomOriginsAllowed)
                                 options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                                     builder => builder.WithOrigins(AllowedOrigins)
                                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                                         .AllowCredentials()
                                         );
                             else
                                 options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                                     builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                                         );
                         });
                         
                         services.AddSignalR(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
                         services.AddOcelot().AddDelegatingHandler<NoGzipDelegatingHandler>(true);
                     })
                    .Configure(app =>
                    {
                        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
                        app.UseWebSockets();
                        app.UseOcelot().Wait();
                    });
```

And my hub configuration is:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapHub<BookingCancelNotificationHub>("/bookingCancelNotificationHub");
        });
```

Specifications

- Ocelot Version: 15.0.6
- @microsoft/signalr Version: 5.0.1 (also downgraded to version 3.1.0)
- .Net Core: 3.1
- Platform: Windows